# Dynamic function call to a class's function, using settimeout

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic

I have a class like structure in javascript, Im attempting to invoke a sibling function using a passed in function name. 
This is difficulty to explain so let me show you an example of what im trying to accomplish..

```
function windowFactory(){
    this.init = function(functionName,args[]){
        SetTimeout(functionName(args),2000)
    }
    this.func1 = function(var1){
        alert(var1);
    }
    this.func2 = function(var1, var2){
        alert(var1+var2);
    }
}
var win1 = new windowFactory();
win1.init("func1","hello");
var win2 = new windowFactory();
win2.init("func2","world","!");
```

Please note that this is only a demo function, syntax errors / typos included.
Now i had this working using a dreaded Eval when it was outside the class...

```
eval(funcName+"('"+darray[1]+"','"+darray[2]+"')");
```

It just required it being outside the Class and passed in dummy values for parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var windowFactory = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.init = function(functionName){
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      setTimeout(function() {
          self[functionName].apply(self, args);
      }, 2000);
  };
  this.func1 = function(var1){
      alert(var1);
  };
  this.func2 = function(var1, var2){
      alert(var1+var2);
  };
};
var win1 = new windowFactory();
win1.init("func1","hello");
var win2 = new windowFactory();
win2.init("func2","world","!");
```

Note the custom self reference `var self = this;`. This is used because when the timed out function is called, the `this` object will be `window` (at least in a web browser).

Another clarification: To address a specific object property in JavaScript you can do in the following ways:

```
object.property; // Or
object['property']; // When you have a string literal, like in your example
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for. This has been holding me back for days!